# Force android camera resolution to lower resolution from browser when user try to upload file

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, android-camera

So in my application, I am allowing users to upload files. So after clicking on input he gets options like pick up the video from the gallery or open camera to take video and upload it. And this is something that androids give by themselves. If the user opens its camera and record video in HD so even a small video like 10sec videos goes to 100MB. I want to restrict the user camera to the least resolution. So that the video or photo that he takes, the size won't be much.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the resolution or any other camera setting when you are launching the camera app by Intent. So there are two solutions to your problem.

1. Integrate Camera2API in your app and create a custom camera with all controls in your hand.(complex to implement but fast to use)
2. Post process the video to lower the resolution after the video has been recorded(easy to implement but needs post processing time)